# Can't dynamically disable dragover event listener (removeEventLIstener)

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

I have a page with a list of Divs that, using drag/drop, allows the user to re-organize the list. Some are empty "containers" and some contain child content that can be drag/dropped between the Divs. When the page is generated, there are EMPTY divs added that can be dropped into, which have inline: ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" functions so they accept a drop. The divs with content do not have these events because you can't drop on a div that already has contents. As the user drags content from the source div to an empty target div, I need to DISABLE drop on the target div because it now will have contents. Conversely, I need to ENABLE drop on the source div because it becomes empty.

I've read multiple threads about addEventListener/removeEventListener and have tried many of the suggestions. I can use addEventListener to enable drop on the emptied source div, but I cannot figure out how to remove drop on the drop/filled-in target div using removeEventLister. I've also tried the cloneNode methods suggested in various threads.

My understanding so far is that Javascript needs to get a "handle" on the listener function when you add it, so it can be referenced to remove it. So the first thing I tried was to add the drop/dragover listeners when the page loads, rather than when the page is generated, thinking that would give JS a handle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("lotdropbox");
    for(let i = coll.length;i > 0; i--) {
       var thisdiv = "L" + i.toString() ;  // divs are named in order L1, L2, L3, etc.
       var cn = document.getElementById(thisdiv).children[0] ;
       if (cn == undefined) {
          makedropable(thisdiv) ;
       }
   }        
});

function makedropable(divid) {
  // when we cut or drag off the contents of a lotbox, we have to make that box dropable - THIS WORKS
  var element = document.getElementById(divid) ;
  // the "() =>" prefix adds the function WITHOUT executing it
  element.addEventListener("drop", () => drop(event) );
  element.addEventListener("dragover", () => allowDrop(event) );
}
```

What I ran into was, in JS I could not add the event without it immediately executing, which seems weird, so I found a thread about using () => . But I understand that this makes the function anonymous, which defeats the purpose.

So first, I don't understand why without the "() =>" the function tries to execute when added (there is no event yet when adding the listener). If I could prevent that, then maybe I could leave out ()=> and JS would register handles. As I said, I tried falling back on cloning the target Div to remove listeners, but it did not remove the listeners.

So, I'm stuck. It seems to me removeEventListener should be so much simpler!!!

P.S. forgot to include my drag/drop functions, here:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
    
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
        
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var datafrom = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      
    // add dropability to div cut dragged from, using un-used lang property to store source container div id - THIS WORKS
    var lastdiv = document.getElementById(datafrom).lang ;
    if (lastdiv != "") {
        makedropable(lastdiv) ;
        document.getElementById(datafrom).lang = "" ;  //reset
    }
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(datafrom));
    var datato = ev.target.id;
             
    // remove dropability from this div - THIS DOES NOT WORK!
    var element = document.getElementById(datato) ;
    element.removeEventListener("drop", drop);
    element.removeEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);
}
```

P.P.S. In the mean time, I'm trying to see if there's another way to just toggle a Div between being "dropable" or not. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I figured this out. Not by using add/removeEventListener, but rather by adding the listeners in-line when the page is generated and then using this, which I found in a 2016 post here: stackoverflow.com/questions/37587353/…